# *one piece ch 1000 spoiler* what does チャキ mean?

Tags: meaning, usage, katakana, manga

I just read this chapter and was wondering what this sfx meant.

for context; luffy is passing big mom & kaido while zoro is observing what he is doing.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the character have some weapon? It's typically like a clank between sword and sheath or that of gun's safety...

Comment: ohh yeah, he has three swords. he probably unsheathes one of his swords. thanks alot :)

Comment: Note that チャキ is not the sound of unsheathing. He probably is preparing to unsheathe, and that movement produces the sound.